# Inserting Foreign key using primary key in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am making a form in asp using C# and my task is to make a course and packages detail and insert the  , i have make three tables one is Course which contain Id(pk) and Course-name, packages table contain Id(pk) and pkg-name and other table is Pkg-detail which contain Pkg-id(pk) and it is foreign key for Id in packages table and other attribute is course-id it is foreign key for course(ID) and my task is when i select pkg-name from drop down and course from check box from asp form that particular Id for pkg-name  and Id for Course-name will insert in third table pkg-detail as i am new i have searched lot but cannot find related answer.

```
SqlCommand cmm = new SqlCommand("Pkc", con);

cmm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", drop1.SelectedValue);
cmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", check1.SelectedValue);

con.Open();
cmm.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pkc]
@course nvarchar(50),
@pname nvarchar(50)
```

AS
begin
    insert into Pkg(CourseId)values((select Id from Courses where CourseName=@course));
    insert into Pkg(PkgId) values ((select Id from PKgCode where PkgName=@pname))
    end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mentioned your problem, but from your text it seems that you want to pass courceID and PackageID into your StoredProc, your code has a problem, since dropdown.SelectedValue is string by `AddWithValue` you will add two `string` parameter while I think they should be `integer`. So cast them as `int` or use other method that accepts type of parameter.

### Edit

Base on comments it seems that your procedure should be like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pkc] @course nvarchar(50), @pname nvarchar(50) 
AS 
begin 
  declare @courceID int
  declare @pkgID int
  select @courceID = Id from Courses where CourseName=@course
  select @pkgID = Id from PKgCode where PkgName=@pname
  insert into Pkg-Detail(CourseId,PkgId) values(@courceID, @pkgID) 
end
```